# Typescript/RequireJS having issues with an MVC application

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I have the following code in Visual Studio, in an MVC application;

`/scripts/bin/models/ViewModel.ts`

```
export class ViewModel {
  // view model code
}
```

Now, I have downloaded `requirejs`, and set the build mode for typescript to `AMD` type, so that its output looks such as....

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
```

And so on ...

So then I declare my `app/config.js` file like so;

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/scripts/bin'
});
```

And I try to load this up, I have requirejs loaded into the scripts, and attempt to call it...

```
require(['models/ViewModel'], function (viewModel) {
        console.log("test");
});
```

And I am simply told that it is an invalid call. No other details. The path that it shows is completely correct, too. Is there some kind of additional configuration required? The requirejs documentation is extremely vague about this.

## SOLUTION

This turned out to have nothing to do with `requirejs`, but instead had to do with IIS.

By default, IIS has a rule known as `hiddenSegments`. It does not allow you to bring in any code from a folder with `bin` in the path. I simply renamed the folder from `bin` to something else, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using require.js with TypeScript is a combination of your .html, require.config, module exports and imports.
For a step-by-step guide on moving from CommonJs TypeScript to AMD and require.js, have a look [here.](http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/typescript-organizing-your-code-with-amd-modules-and-require-js/)
Have fun.

Comment: This guide helped a bit, though it turns out my problem was completely unrelated to requireJS, will be posting it soon.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript compiler doesn't have any knowledge of your `require.config` - so when you use paths relative to that baseUrl they look invalid to the compiler.

Until something is done to bridge that slight mismatch (i.e. make the compiler super-clever so it can look for `require.config` sections and use them to check paths) it is easier not to set a baseUrl and use the full path in your import statements:

```
import vm = require('./scripts/bin/models/ViewModel');
```

Comment: Oh no, the require imports within typescript files work, I am talking about trying to use it anywhere else. For instance, in my `_Layout.cshtml`, I have a line trying to call the view model, and it just tells me the file doesn't exist - it even gives the right path for it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the require call is done *with* `[]` and not just

```
require('models/ViewModel', function (viewModel) {  // this is an error 
        console.log("test");
});
```

See : http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#requireargs